# What's the difference between ts.createSourceFile and ts.factory.createSourceFile?

Tags: typescript, abstract-syntax-tree

There are two apis to create source file in typescript api: ts.createSourceFile and ts.factory.createSourceFile, but what's the difference between them? Why there are two ways to do the same thing?

Obviously, the arguments are different, but I don't think it's the reason.